# Is CompletableFuture<Optional<Object>> supported as return type in SpringData?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Recently I found some weird problem using spring-data-couchbase with spring, just trying to implement a find operation in a Repository. Trying to solve my issue I saw in this old page (https://www.humansreadcode.com/spring-boot-completablefuture/) that `CompletableFuture<Optional<SomeObject>>` wasn't supported as a return value.

Is that true (I couldn´t find documentation related)?

If not, is there any reason for that even when both `CompletableFuture` and `Optional` are valid return types?

Comment: People will offer help if you can give more details what "weird problem" you got using `CompletableFuture<Optional<A>>`?

Comment: I'm just looking info for CompletableFuture<Optional<SomeObject>> as a return type in spring data, is it supported? Where can I found some info?